# Excel: How to separate number/text in cell based on its font styles (underline, strikethrough)

Tags: excel

I have a column of cells that contains numbers like this:

***Cell Values:***
[image]

The cells include the new and old values together. The underlined digit is the new digit while the strikethrough digit is the old digit. Together it shows the old and new numbers.

I want to separate the columns into old and new values.

Something like this

| Old number | New Number |
| --- | --- |
| 0.15 | 0.17 |

Can someone suggest how to do it?

Comment: You need `VBA` macro.

Comment: What excel version is this? Excel online or desktop?

Comment: @shahkalpesh Microsoft 365, version 2202, desktop

Answer (score 2):

This is the VBA macro code you will have to use and call.

```
Public Sub ExtractOldAndNewValues()
Dim i As Integer
Dim cellValue As String
Dim newValue As String
Dim oldValue As String

For Each cell In Selection
    For i = 1 To cell.Characters.Count
        cellValue = cellValue & cell.Characters(i, 1).Text
        'Debug.Print cellValue
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Underline = 2 Then
            newValue = cellValue
            cellValue = Mid(cellValue, 1, Len(cellValue) - 1)
        End If
        
        If cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.Strikethrough Then
            oldValue = cellValue
            cellValue = Mid(cellValue, 1, Len(cellValue) - 1)
        End If
    Next
    If newValue = "" Then
        newValue = cellValue
    End If
    If oldValue = "" Then
        oldValue = cellValue
    End If
    
    cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = oldValue
    cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = newValue
Next
End Sub
```